# Apache JMeter: Error: Java version is too low to run JMeter

Tags: macos, jmeter

The [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) always shows:

```
$ sh jmeter
Error: Java version is too low to run JMeter. Needs at least Java >= 1.8.0.
```

But I got the java version in terminal as:

```
$ java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

What's the right way for me? The newest JAVA SDK should be [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

```
Environments:
macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
apache-jmeter-3.3
```

Comment: According to Release Notes.

```JMeter does not yet support JAVA 9, next JMeter version will support it, you can help and follow progress on this item in Bug 61529.```

http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Comment: ok, I'm trying to use Java 8 now.

Comment: JMeter 4 is now fully compatible with Java 9: http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [bug 61529](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61529) Java 9 support will be added in the next release.

See [JMeter Release Notes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) and [What's New in JMeter 3.3? for more details](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3).

You should have previous Java versions under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` folder, try using Java 8 from there. If you cannot for some reason try the following alternative approaches:

- Run JMeter as `java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar` instead of running the shell script
- Try [nightly build of JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html), it might be the case the issue is already fixed in it.

Comment: It's working when I downgrade the Java sdk to 8, thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to throw away whole the running scripts then you can only edit them by removing the wrong version checking in files bin/jmeter and bin/jmeter.sh.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter executable `bin/jmeter` is a shell script, you can modify it as you like.. you can skip the Java version check totally. I am talking about older JMeter version like 2 or 3. Now for 5.4.1, maybe for 4 and 5, it will consider JAVA_HOME properly without my fix here.

Or, if you don't want to remove so much code, here's a way to take JAVA_HOME into consideration.

Apparently, this paragraph below does not do the its work right:

```sh
MINIMAL_VERSION=1.6.0

# Check if Java is present and the minimal version requierement
_java=`type java | awk '{ print $ NF }'`   # <<<<<<<<<<< here is the problem
CURRENT_VERSION=`"$_java" -version 2>&1 | awk -F'"' '/version/ {print $2}'`
minimal_version=`echo $MINIMAL_VERSION | awk -F'.' '{ print $2 }'`
current_version=`echo $CURRENT_VERSION | awk -F'.' '{ print $2 }'`
if [ $current_version ]; then
    if [ $current_version -lt $minimal_version ]; then
             echo "Error: Java version is too low to run JMeter. Needs at least Java >= ${MINIMAL_VERSION}." 
             exit 1
    fi
else
     echo "Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation."
     exit 1
fi
```

I have Java 11 and Java 8 both installed, and `java -version` will use Java 11. So `CURRENT_VERSION` will print `11.0.11` and does not pass the check, because the code will compare `0` with `6`, but actually it should compare `11.0` with `1.6`. It is a great compatibility issue with Java 11 version naming, I would say; I mean, I had problem with it when Java 9 comes out, too.

I think it should take into consideration the `JAVA_HOME` env variable, as Maven does. For Maven I can create alias like `mvn8` to set `JAVA_HOME` first and run, so it will use the Java executable in that. Similarly I have `mvn11` as another alias.

```sh
$ alias mvn8
alias mvn8='JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 mvn -Dstyle.color=auto'
```

I want to do the same to jmeter, so I changed this line

```
_java=`type java | awk '{ print $ NF }'`
```

to:

```sh
# Check if Java is present and the minimal version requirement, taking into consideration `$JAVA_HOME`
if [ -z $JAVA_HOME ] ; then 
    echo JAVA_HOME not set, will check java version without it
    _java=`type java | awk '{ print $ NF }'`
else
    _java=`type $JAVA_HOME/bin/java | awk '{ print $ NF }'`
fi
```

And I define an alias for it, too:

```sh
alias jmeter8='JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /opt/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter'
```

So that it will always use Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by running CMD as admin.
It is strange but it worked like that, I hope the answer will help some persons.